# Java Server Based Highcharts and width limitation

Tags: highcharts

We started to use highcharts on server side. And I found a limitation of image width.

http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/52-serverside-generated-charts
width   Set the exact pixel width of the exported image or pdf. This overrides the -scale parameter. The maximum allowed width is 2000px

Can it be changed in some config files or it's hard-coded thing. If so, why?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can changed in the ExportController.java file, in the Highcharts-export-web module. 
Change this line [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/master/exporting-server/java/highcharts-export/highcharts-export-web/src/main/java/com/highcharts/export/controller/ExportController.java#L55) to alter the maximum allowed width.

It's not a bad idea to have this in a property file, but on the other hand, exporting images bigger than 2000px is also a bit rare.